# Is there a hook that runs after a user logs in?

Tags: hooks, login, actions

I am writing a plugin that fetches some extended user info from a remote service and I need it to execute its function each time a user logs in.

Is there a hook that gets fired after login that I can add an action to?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The action hook wp_login runs when the user logs in - it can run a simple function.

```
function do_anything() {
    //do stuff
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
```

documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

The real breadwinner here is `wp_authenticate` which has a bit of documentation. It passes an array with the given username and password, which gives you the opportunity to pass info to the remote service, if necessary.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate

and to change the redirect URL after login, there is the filter `login_redirect`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Answer (score 11):

<s>I would caution against using `wp_login`.  It is deprecated and in later versions of WordPress it may not work at all.  Instead try the [`wp_signon`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function.</s>

**Edit**: The [`wp_login` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login) is deprecated but the [`wp_login` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) is still fine to use.

Comment: yes wp_login action still works.