# Do more action after login successfully

Tags: login, wp-redirect

I have a simple requirement, after user login set the login user session and then redirect to another page.

Yes, I found some similar page from here [is-there-a-hook-that-runs-after-a-user-logs-in](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28522/is-there-a-hook-that-runs-after-a-user-logs-in)

As the post said, what I need to do is like this:

```
function set_blog_session(){
    $_SESSION['blogger'] = get_current_user_id();
    wp_redirect("http://www.google.com");//just for test
}
add_action('wp_login', 'set_blog_session');
```

But I got nothing.

First, `get_current-user_id()` always returns `0`.
Second, **no redirect at all**.

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `exit` after using the [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect):

From the Codex:

> wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be
>   followed by exit.

---

For your hook, you could pass a parameter in your callback function to get the user login and then use [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) to get the ID.

```
function set_blog_session($user_login){
    $user_obj = get_user_by('login', $user_login );
    $_SESSION['blogger'] = $user_obj->ID;

    wp_redirect("http://www.google.com");
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'set_blog_session');
```

Comment: thanks man, yes, need to be add exit. And what's wrong with my first problem, why get_current_user_id() got 0?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: it works man, but I wonder, why use get_current_user_id() not working, because I have been logon, so it should be get the current user id ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know why `get_current_user_id()` doesn't work, maybe someone else will help us understand that point.

Comment: Shouldn't have to call get_current_user_id, the hook passes the $WP_User object: do_action( 'wp_login', string $user_login, WP_User $user )